# error when a non bot member comes online (presenceUpdate)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my bot to send this message when a bot goes online or offline. it works sometimes but when a human member comes online i get this error: `UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`.
My code:

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate",(oldPresence,newPresence)=>{
    if(newPresence.user.bot){
        client.channels.cache.get("799082492065087498").send(oldPresence.user.tag+" is "+newPresence.status);
    };
});
```

Comment: Please mention that this is server side or client? And what is oldPresence and when it sets?

Comment: client side api, oldPresence is the presence after newPresence when a user comes online oldPresence is offline and newPresence is online. when user goes offline oldPresence is online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that this code is server side:
Definitely you didn't send newPresence in client side that you get this Error.
So you can check newPresence before newPresence.user.
Like this:

```
client.on("presenceUpdate",(oldPresence,newPresence)=>{
    if(newPresence && newPresence.user.bot){
        client.channels.cache.get("799082492065087498").send(oldPresence.user.tag+" is "+newPresence.status);
    };
});
```

Comment: This is still not fully right - it will solve OP's issue, but there shouldn't be `oldPresence` used at all, since `newPresence` is the obj after it has been updated - i.e. the new presence, the `user#tag` doesnt usually change - its just more reliable